# How to get raw output in python hmac sha256?

Tags: python, hmac

In php to get raw output we do,

```
echo hash_hmac('ripemd160', 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.', 'secret', true);
```

as the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) suggest the forth param is used to specify if the output returned needs to be in raw format or not.

In Python3 I'm doing the following,

```
hashed_string = hmac.new(secret_key, bytes(string_to_be_hashed, 'utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

which is returning me a string which is lowercase hexits.

How do I get raw binary data from the same?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Do not use ``.hexdigest()`` if you do not want hex. Use just ``.digest()`` instead.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thanks a lot it worked!